# freeradius 3.0.13 used custome attribute reply

Tags: freeradius, radius

I am configuring Freeradius.

It is authentication reject when i try to use custom attribute register in radreply table.

This is my test operation and error case.

Ⅰ. Insert record to radreply table

```
> insert into radreply values(null,"user1","Custom-TEST1",":=","56789");

> select * from radreply;
 +----+----------+---------------+----+-----------+
 | id | username | attribute     | op | value     |
 +----+----------+---------------+----+-----------+
 |  1 | user1    | Custom-NET01  | := | 12345     |
 +----+----------+---------------+----+-----------+
```

Ⅱ. Configure dictionary file

$ vi /etc/raddb/dictionary

ATTRIBUTE   Custom-TEST1        3000    integer

I checked by debbug mode. Then i can see this messages.

(0) sql: ERROR: Error parsing value: Unknown or invalid value "10.0.0.1" for attribute Custom-TEST1

(0) sql: ERROR: Error parsing user data from database result

(0) sql: ERROR: SQL query error getting reply attributes

Please tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you've defined your custom attribute as an integer (which in this case means a 32bit unsigned integer).  You're then later, trying to assign an IPv4 address to this integer, which is invalid.

If you want to assign an ipv4 address to your attribute, it needs to be defined as an ipaddr type.